# Insert a word into the middle of a list and print out the modified list

Tags: python

I'm doing a Computer Science Lab with Python.

I've tried using some functions like s.insert (hot day, warm morning) but this doesn't help me add the value to the middle of the list.  Can someone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: show your real code plz ;)

Comment: s="hello world, good morning, red light, green apple"
>>> s.insert(0,"hot day")   I'm trying to add "hot day" to the middle of the list.

Comment: `'str' object has no attribute 'insert'`, 
your code does not even run

Answer (score 3):

Do this using `insert`

`s.insert(index_to_insert, value)`

For example:

`s.insert(1, "hello")` will insert the string "hello" as the second element of the list (since indexing starts at 0)

The problem is that you have `s` as a string not a list. You must convert to list **then** do the insertion as follows:

```
s = s.split()
s.insert(1, "warm")
s = ' '.join(s)
```

Comment: I try that but it doesn't recognize the insert function

Comment: @user3474829, That's impossible. What error does it give you?

Comment: @user3474829, Hold on. According to your comment under your question, your s is not a list but rather a string. `insert` is for lists.

Comment: @user3474829, See my updated answer for your problem

Comment: @user3474829, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks